# How to configure LightVpn to work without root

Tags: java, android

I found this project https://github.com/PeterCxy/LightVPN which is perfect for what I want to do, but it requires root access. Is there a way to make this work if I sign the APK with a platform key and place it in the system/app directory if the device is not rooted?

```
public static Process run(String command) throws IOException {
  ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("su");
  Process p = builder.start();
  DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
  dos.writeBytes(command + "\n");
  dos.flush();
  dos.writeBytes("exit\n");
  dos.flush();
  return p;
}
```

Comment: Wait a minute... How can you sign with a platform key???

Comment: for a custom made rom